# Data visualization Autodesk Forge: CSV Data Adapter , SQLite Data Adapter

Tags: csv, visualization, autodesk-forge

I need information about CSV data Adapter in Autodesk forge. Unfortunately, this information was deleted from the main page (https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/overview/).
Would you please guide me, on how I can find information about CSV data Adapter again?

**A few weeks ago:**

[image]

**New page:** (https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/overview/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The original DataViz tutorials and reference application did not turn out as we were hoping so we're in the process of rebuilding them. We have a new DataViz/IoT demo app available here: https://aps-iot-extensions-demo.autodesk.io (source code: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo), and we're planning to add a new DataViz tutorial to https://aps.autodesk.com/tutorials in early 2023. Please stay tuned!